# Update List Items from Excel

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint document list with more than 700+ list items. Now few items have empty value for one column. Manual editing is time consuming. I want to update multiple list items. I have exported the list and want to now synchronize the excel sheet table with the SharePoint List. How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use"Export to Excel" to export the document library to excel?

By default, "Export to Excel" is a one-way sync which just syncs changes from SharePoint to Excel, and is unable to sync changes from Excel to SharePoint. It is a limit currently, there is a [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36215233-two-way-sync-between-sharepoint-and-excel) about this feature, you can vote up it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, although I am aware of it but I want to sync from Excel to Sharepoint List. Usually i export to excel...then make the changes in excel in one go so that I don't have to switch to sharepoint list again and again. then I go to list to make changes one by one. That is a tedious work and it will be good if somehow I can sync directly from the Excel.